# rake and utf-8 char in appication path

Tags: ruby, utf-8, rake

I use an application which I compile using rake. The problem is if I set my application directory in a path containing non US-ASCII char, the compilation fails.

For exemple:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/my_app
rake
```

==> it works

```
cd /home/user/Téléchargements/my_app
rake
```

==> it doesn't work

My system is full utf-8

How can I avoid this?

For information the application that I try to compile is subtle :

```
hg clone http://hg.subforge.org/subtle
cd subtle
rake
```

Here the full error message:

```
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke config (first_time)
** Execute config
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for stdarg.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for wordexp.h... yes
rake aborted!
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:785:in `[]'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:785:in `checking_for'
/home/silkmoth/Téléchargements/subtle/Rakefile:335:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => config
```

Comment: Which Ruby version is it? MRI 1.9 introduced a lot of improvements when it comes to character encoding support.

Comment: my version of ruby is ruby 1.9.3p0

Comment: Not enough information. Rake works fine for me in directories like this. One of your rake tasks must be doing something incompatible. "it works" and "it doesn't work" are not sufficient to help you. Try running with `rake --trace` to get a full stack trace and error message.

Comment: ok so here is the error message:

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 chars in yous code?

Comment: I have launch this command to test that:`for i in */*/*; do echo $i;file -i $i;done` and all files appears to be us-ascii

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the encoding of the files, but the non-ascii symbols in your path ('Téléchargements').

Apparently, the exception happens in #checking_for from mkmf on line 785 in combination with rake. As author of the Rakefile, there is nothing I can do about that, besides reporting that upstream and/or find a way to avoid the method at all.

Quick fix is use a path without non-ascii symbols, sorry.